# How can I write 'METAPOST' logo in LaTeX?

Tags: logos

I'd like to type `METAPOST` and `METAFONT` logo in my LaTeX document, but I couldn't find clear way to do that. What font should I use? (in pdfLaTeX) Or is there any command to write that? (for example `\LaTeX`)

Comment: `\usepackage{hologo}` and `\hologo{METAPOST}` and `\hologo{METAFONT}`

Comment: You can find other useful informations here: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=logos

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.